# High score policy for users that don't sign into Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

I designed a game to save high scores to Game Center leaderboard.
Now, my project manager says. "So those who have not enabled Game Center, let them save high scores locally."

Okay but that could cause confusion in occasions like:

- User plays without GC and gets a high score. Then the user signs into GC and switch to your game again. Should you remove display of local high scores alltogether?

Is there a general "do this" when it comes to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

IMO the biggest concern is maintaining the user's high score. If there's a situation in which the user has high score A locally and high score B in Game Center then display max(A, B).

Answer (score 1):

Always cache or save high scores locally. This way, even users with Game Center enabled will be able to see their scores if they're offline and submit whn they reconnect. You can create your own UI for offline scores, and add an indicator that a given score was submitted to Game Center. Then, offer a way of seeing the Game Center scores. (You can either use a custom view controller, or the standard ones.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a "best practice" in this situation, but I have a game which does both, and I ended up doing the following:

- If GC is disabled, you get high scores saved locally.
- If GC is enabled, you get GC high scores.  No local high scores.

Now, when I developed this game, GC was brand new, and many users didn't have it, so local high scores seemed like a requirement.  If I were to develop it today, I'd probably skip local high scores completely.  If you don't have GC, you don't get high scores, period.

Note, though, I'm talking specifically about GC being disabled.  If the user has signed into GC, but it's not available (say, no network connectivity), you should absolutely queue up any earned high scores so that you can send them to GC later, whenever the network is available again.